# Windows 10 Error 1 When Any PIP Install

Tags: python, windows, pip

I get the error 1 when I try to `pip install <module>`. Any module. Ive tried cx_freeze and pyside tonight, and i really need both. How do I resolve this?

cx_freeze error:
`Command "c:\users\other\desktop\python3.5.2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Other\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-fzrlj2j2\\cx-freeze\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Other\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nv1cmthe-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Other\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-fzrlj2j2\cx-freeze\`

Comment: It's executing a child process to run setup.py, which fails with an exit code of 1. That's a generic failure code, so there's not much to go on. For cx_freeze I tried `pip --verbose install cx_freeze`. Apparently the problem is that a "cxfreeze-postinstall" script is missing. I found an open [issue #158](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/158/cannot-install-cx_freeze-with-pip3-python) for this installation problem on the cx_freeze issue tracker.

Comment: i still get the same error

Comment: Did you expect `--verbose` would fix the problem? I mentioned it as a diagnostic technique to gather more information, which in this case led to the linked problem. Follow up with Anthony Tuininga to see whether you can help fix the problem or just to let him know that there's at least one more person waiting for him to fix it. Apparently it's been "on the list of things to do" since November.

Comment: Who's he? thanks tho